# Android QR code, Datamatrix and Aztec scanner

Tags: android, qr-code, datamatrix, aztec-barcode

I am looking for good QR code / Datamatrix / Aztec scanner application for Android. It should can:

1. read color QR codes like [this](http://freenuts.com/images/qrcode-cx.gif) and negative QR codes like [this](http://www.sundoginteractive.com/images/uploads/Figure-3.jpg),
2. read Datamatrix,
3. read Aztec.

The best of is [i-nigma](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threegvision.products.inigma.Android), which can read even [this](http://www.trendleaks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/custom-qr-code-art-for-tonare_thumb.jpg) or [this](http://www.trendleaks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/qr-code-art-neon-design.jpg)! But it can't read Aztec :-(.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try searching Google Play?

Comment: Yes, and tried a lot of code scanner applications from there.

Answer (score 3):

after a quick search :-)

[NeoReader QR & Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.gavitec.android&hl=en)

> FEATURES
>
> - Scans all standard 1D and 2D code types – **QR, Data Matrix, Aztec**, EAN, UPC, Code 39, Code 128, PDF 417 and more!
> - Automatic detection of code type

Answer (score 1):

The de facto standard for Android is [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android). It reads all of these things and more.

Comment: I tried it as my first QR code scanner. And it can not read Aztec codes.

Comment: Did you enable Aztec codes? it is off by default.

Comment: You are right, I missed this option in settings.

Comment: I tried NeoReader and Barcode Scanner with Aztec code and found NeoReader to be noticeably faster. It also doesn’t need the code to be precisely positioned in tiny box as Barcode Scanner does. However it is ad supported.